# debugging exception with windbg

Tags: c++, exception, com, windbg

Need help debugging COM with windbg, below is call stack and access violation exception

> kb

```
000007fe`edefcba0 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 00000000`09492c50 000007fe`fd661592 : IEFRAME!IUnknown_SafeReleaseAndNullPtr<IAdviseSink>+0x13
000007fe`edee99a8 : 00000000`13c55f20 00000000`00000001 00000000`05e8f1c0 00000000`00000000 : IEFRAME!CConnectionPoint::UnadviseAll+0x44
000007fe`ee0b531f : 00000000`00000000 00000000`13c55d80 00000000`00000001 00000000`03d86d70 : IEFRAME!CConnectionPoint::~CConnectionPoint+0x18
000007fe`ee07ef24 : 00000000`13d79158 000007fe`fe21a066 00000000`13d79158 00000000`05e8f260 : IEFRAME!CShellOcx::~CShellOcx+0xf7
000007fe`edefcce1 : 00000000`00000000 000007fe`fe21ab8e 00000000`13a3ff40 00000000`00000000 : IEFRAME!CWebBrowserOC::`vector deleting destructor'+0x14
000007fe`fe219c8f : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`13a3ff40 00000000`00000000 : IEFRAME!CAggregatedUnknown::CUnkInner::Release+0x33
000007fe`fe219a35 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`13d79158 000007fe`edf50530 00000000`13c55dc0 : ole32!CStdIdentity::ReleaseCtrlUnk+0x5b [d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\dcomrem\stdid.cxx @ 1149]
000007fe`fe1f545a : 00000000`00000001 00000000`13d79158 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ole32!CStdMarshal::Disconnect+0x34f [d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\dcomrem\marshal.cxx @ 3454]
000007fe`fe243a71 : 00000000`03d86d70 000007fe`fe212684 00000000`000022e4 00000000`00000005 : ole32!CStdMarshal::DisconnectAndRelease+0x36 [d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\dcomrem\marshal.cxx @ 3161]
000007fe`fe21232b : 00000000`00000005 00000000`03d86d70 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : ole32!COIDTable::ThreadCleanup+0x31bed
000007fe`fe2121f8 : 00000000`03d86d70 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`03ddd360 : ole32!FinishShutdown+0x59 [d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\class\compobj.cxx @ 1035]
000007fe`fe2125a4 : 00000000`03d86d70 00000000`03d86d70 00000000`00000000 000007ff`fffdf000 : ole32!ApartmentUninitialize+0x70 [d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\class\compobj.cxx @ 1291]
000007fe`fe2113ba : 00000000`03d86d70 00000000`03d86d70 00000000`0000000c 00000000`00000050 : ole32!wCoUninitialize+0x1af [d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\class\compobj.cxx @ 2709]
000007fe`fe2551e0 : 80000000`00020000 00000000`03d86d70 80000000`00020000 00000000`00000001 : ole32!CoUninitialize+0xa2 [d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\class\compobj.cxx @ 2632]
000007fe`fe20cdc5 : 00000000`03db1218 00000000`00267a70 00000000`00020401 00000000`00000000 : ole32!DoThreadSpecificCleanup+0x41cf8
00000000`777cb8b4 : 000007fe`fd547060 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`0000000c : ole32!FlsThreadCleanupCallback+0x1d [d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\class\compobj.cxx @ 1816]
00000000`777e6aab : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000007ff`fffdf000 000007ff`fff9e000 : ntdll!RtlProcessFlsData+0x84
00000000`777e6978 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!LdrShutdownThread+0x4b
000007fe`f36a4c46 : 00000000`80004005 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlExitUserThread+0x38
00000000`7769652d : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : IEShims!NS_CreateThread::DesktopIE_ThreadProc+0xd6
00000000`777cc541 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d

0:014> .exr -1
ExceptionAddress: 000007feede1f1df (IEFRAME!IUnknown_SafeReleaseAndNullPtr<IAdviseSink>+0x0000000000000013)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: ffffffffffffffff
Attempt to read from address ffffffffffffffff
```

Is it possible to find out the interface which is getting accessed here.

Comment: did you try  `!analyze -v`?